Numerical Simulation of a Damped, Driven Nonlinear Wave System with Spatially Extended Initial Conditions
I am working on a project that requires creating a specific type of graph, but I am having trouble writing the correct code. The graph should look similar to the one I have attached below.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to correctly create this type of graph? Any help with the code or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
THE PROJECT
The study of the dynamics of the discrete Klein - Gordon equation (DKG) with friction is given by the equation :
$$\ddot {U} _n - k (U_ {n + 1} - 2 U_n + U_ {n - 1}) + \delta\dot {U} \
_n + W' (U_n) = 0;\quad\beta > 0, \delta > 0 \ \ (1)$$
In the above equation, W describes the potential function:$W (U_n) = -\frac {w_d^2} {2} U_n^2 + \frac {\beta w_d^4} {4} U_n^4$
to which every coupled unit $U_n$ adheres. In Eq. (1), the variable $U_n(t)$ is the unknown displacement of the oscillator occupying the n-th position of the lattice, and $k=h^{-2}$ is the discretization parameter. We denote by h the distance between the oscillators of the lattice. The chain (DKG) contains linear damping with a damping coefficient $\delta>0$, while $\beta$ is the coefficient of the nonlinear cubic term.
For the DKG chain (1), we will consider the problem of initial-boundary values, with initial conditions
$$U_n(0) = U_ {n,0} \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{U}_n(0) = U_ {n,1} \in \
\mathbb{R}^{K+2},\ \ (2)$$
and Dirichlet boundary conditions at the boundary points $x_0 = -L/2$ and $x_{K+1} = L/2$, that is,
$$U_0 = U_{K+1} = 0, \quad t \geq 0.\ \ (3)$$
Therefore, when necessary, we will use the short notation $\Delta_d$ for the one-dimensional discrete Laplacian
$$\{\Delta_d U\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} = U_{n+1} - 2U_n + U_{n-1} \ \ (4)$$
Now we want to investigate numerically the dynamics of the system (1)-(2)-(3). Our first aim is to conduct a numerical study of the property of Dynamic Stability of the system, which directly depends on the existence and linear stability of the branches of equilibrium points.
For the discussion of numerical results, it is also important to emphasize the role of the parameter $\omega_d^2$. By changing the time variable $t \rightarrow \frac{t}{h}$ , we rewrite Eq. (1) in the form
\begin{equation}\ddot{U}_n - \Delta_d U + \hat{\delta} \dot{U}_n = \Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^3), \quad t > 0, \quad \Omega_d^2 = h^2 \omega_d^2, \quad \hat{\delta} = h \delta\end{equation}. We consider spatially extended initial conditions of the form:$$ U_n(0) = U_{n,0} = a \sin \left( \frac{j \pi h n}{L} \right), \quad j = 1, \ldots, K $$
where  $ h = \frac{L}{K+1} $ is the distance of the grid and $ a > 0$ is the amplitude of the initial condition
We also assume zero initial velocity:
$\dot{U}_n(0) = U_{n,1} = 0 $.
I want to create the following graphs for $a=2, K=99,L=200,\beta=1, \delta=0.05$ and $\omega_d^2=1$

For the first plot, I created the following code!
(*Parameters*)
a = 2;(*Amplitude of the initial condition*)
j = 2; (*Mode number*)
l = 200; (*Length of the system*)
k = 99; (*number of spatial points*)

(*spatial grid*)
h = l/(k + 1);
n = Range[-l/2, l/2, h]; (*spatial points*)

(*compute u_n(0) for each n*)
uN0 = a*Sin[(j*Pi*h*n)/l];


(*Plotting the initial positions*)ListPlot[Transpose[{n, uN0}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x_n", "u_n"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Initial Positions of DNA Segment at t = 0", 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotRange -> {{-l/2, l/2}, {-3, 3}}]




I don't know how to create a proper code to create the blue graph for my problem
L = 200;  (*Number of base pairs,representing a segment of DNA*)
kappa = 1;    (*discretization parameter*)
omegaD = 1;   (*characteristic frequency*)
beta = 1;    (*Nonlinearity parameter*)
delta = 0.05;   (*Damping coefficient*)
j = 2; (*Mode number*)

k = 99; (*number of spatial points*)
(*spatial grid*)h = L/(k + 1);
nsp = Subdivide[-L/2, L/2, k + 1];(*Spatial points*)

(*Scaled parameters*)omegaD2 = (h^2)*omegaD^2;
deltaHat = h*delta;
a = 2;(*Amplitude of the initial condition*)

(*Sinusoidal initial perturbations to simulate thermal fluctuations*)
initialPositions = Table[x[n][0] == a*Sin[j*Pi*n*h/L], {n, 1, L}];
initialVelocities = 
 Table[x[n]'[0] == 0, {n, 1, L}];  (*Assuming initial rest state*)

(*Boundary Conditions*)
boundaryConditions = {x[1][t] == 0, x[L][t] == 0};

(*Equations*)
equations = 
 Table[x[n]''[t] - kappa (x[n + 1][t] - 2 x[n][t] + x[n - 1][t]) + 
    deltaHat x[n]'[t] + omegaD2^2 (x[n][t] - beta x[n][t]^3) == 
   0, {n, 1, L}];

(*Solve Numerically*)
solution = 
 NDSolveValue[{equations, initialPositions, initialVelocities, 
   boundaryConditions}, Table[x[n], {n, 1, L}], {t, 0, 3000}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic} ];(*Visualization*)

Plot[Evaluate[Table[solution[[n]][t], {n, 1, L}]], {t, 0, 3000}, 
PlotLegends -> Table[StringJoin["Base ", ToString[n]], {n, 1, L}], 
PlotRange -> All]
'''


I don't have the correct plot for a=2 what is the correct plot? You are asking someone to figure that out by looking at hard to read screen shot. You should make that more clear which plot you want to generate. May be circle it or something.

For the first plot I think this is ok! It is not the same as in the paper. It has half the frequency?

@Nasser Yes it had half frequency. Now I have provided the correct code and plot

Your code does not even run.  https://i.sstatic.net/2EKij4M6.png  are you sure you included everything? And please do not use l for variable name. It looks like 1 and makes your code hard to use. You can use L as that is not used by Mathematica.

Look at your initialPositions this is not even an equality. Why are you passing a list of values for NDSolve? This list is not an initial conditions, so what is it doing in the call? You also have boundaryConditions as {x[0][t] == 0, x[201][t] == 0} but your ode's starts from x[1] and end at x[200]

@Nasser I have updated the code but still, I am stuck when I am trying to solve the system of equations

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos From what paper the blue plot has been taken?

@AlexTrounev It is from the same paper I was studying the last time! Could I send you my notebook later to see what is going wrong to my code?

Ok!  Please, show me your notebook.

@AlexTrounev I have updated the initial post with my code because  I don't have your email sir

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Please, see my paper with email https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/8/824

@AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Please see update to my answer with your code free of typos.

@AlexTrounev Thank you very much! I was about to send my notebook

We can play with parameters to make same plot, but with current data we have
(*parameters*)a = 2;(*Amplitude of the initial condition*)
j = 2; (*Mode number*)
L = 200; (*Length of the system*)

omegad = 1; (*characteristic frequency*)
beta = 1;(*Nonlinearity parameter*)

(*damping coefficient*)
delta = 0.05;

(*spatial grid*)
h = 1;
grid = Range[-L/2, L/2, h];(*Spatial points*)
k = Length[grid]; (*number of spatial points*)
(*discretization parameter*)
(*Scaled parameters*)
omegad2 = (h^2)*omegad^2;
deltaHat = h*delta;

tmax = 3000; (*Maximum time*)


var = Table[u[i][t], {i, k}]; eqs = 
 Table[u[i]''[t] - (u[i + 1][t] + u[i - 1][t] - 2  u[i][t]) + 
    deltaHat  u[i]'[t] - omegad2  (u[i][t] - beta  u[i][t]^3) == 
   0, {i, 2, k - 1}]; bc = {u[1][t] == 0, u[k][t] == 0};
ic = Join[Thread[var == a  Sin[2 j Pi  grid/L]] /. t -> 0, 
   Table[u[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, k - 1}]];

sol = NDSolve[Join[eqs, {u[1]'[t] == 0, u[k]'[t] == 0}, ic], 
    var, {t, 0,  tmax}];

Visualization
{ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Initial Positions of DNA Segment at t = 0", 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], 
 Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{grid, var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(n\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Positions of DNA Segment at t = 3000", 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}],
   ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{grid, 
     var /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tmax}], {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}}]]}


Update 1. Original code without typos
L = 200;  (*Number of base pairs,representing a segment of DNA*)
kappa = 1;    (*discretization parameter*)
omegaD = 1;   (*characteristic frequency*)
beta = 1;    (*Nonlinearity parameter*)
delta = 0.05;   (*Damping coefficient*)
j = 2; (*Mode number*)

tmax = 3000; (*Maximum time*)
(*spatial grid*)h = 1;
nsp = Range[-L/2, L/2, h](*Spatial points*);

km = Length[nsp](*number of spatial points*);
(*Scaled parameters*)omegaD2 = (h^2)*omegaD^2;
deltaHat = h*delta;
a = 2;(*Amplitude of the initial condition*)

(*Sinusoidal initial perturbations to simulate thermal fluctuations*)
var = Table[x[i][t], {i, Length[nsp]}];
initialPositions = 
  Table[x[i][0] == a*Sin[j  2*Pi*nsp[[i]]/L], {i, Length[nsp]}];
initialVelocities = 
  Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, 
    km - 1}];  (*Assuming initial rest state*)

(*Boundary Conditions*)
boundaryConditions = {x[1][t] == 0, x[km][t] == 0};

(*Equations*)
equations = 
  Table[x[n]''[t] - kappa  (x[n + 1][t] - 2  x[n][t] + x[n - 1][t]) + 
     deltaHat  x[n]'[t] - omegaD2^2  (x[n][t] - beta  x[n][t]^3) == 
    0, {n, 2, km - 1}];

(*Solve Numerically*)
solution = 
  NDSolve[Join[equations, boundaryConditions, initialPositions, 
    initialVelocities], var, {t, 0, tmax}];(*Visualization*)

Visualization
{ListPlot[Transpose[{nsp, var} /. solution[[1]] /. t -> 0], 
  PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[var /. solution[[1]] /. t -> tmax]}


